# doublestrike blocking with kusari-gama

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a 4/4 creature with double strike and equipped with [Kusari-Gama](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKusari-Gama%5d). I get attacked by a 5/5 and 3 2/2's. I block the 5/5 with my 4/4. Do I take damage from the 2/2's even though they die in the first strike phase?

Answer (score 10):

### You will take damage, because the creatures *don't* die

If a creature without first strike or double strike is killed during the first strike step, it will not deal damage.  It is not on the battlefield during the regular damage step, therefore it cannot deal damage.

**However**, [Kusari-gama](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKusari-gama%5d) does not work the way you think it does.  Kusari-gama reads

> Whenever equipped creature deals damage to a **blocking** creature, Kusari-Gama deals that much damage to each other creature defending player controls.

In the scenario you've presented, your double striking creature is dealing damage to an **attacking** creature.  Therefore, Kusari-gama's effect is *not* triggered, and no damage is dealt to the attacking 2/2s.  Since the 2/2s do not actually die in the first strike step, and they were not blocked, you take damage from them.

Were you to use a card like [Brigid, Hero of Kinsbaile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrigid%2c%20Hero%20of%20Kinsbaile%5d) to deal damage to the attacking 2/2s at any point before they deal damage, then they would die and you would not take damage.